# Fluid simulation - in-flow that doesnt start from frame 1 shows domain as an object until the inflow kicks in

Tags: fluid-simulation

Fluid simulation problem:
i have a fluid simulation that i want to animate.
i do NOT want the flow to start on frame 1. I want it to start on frame 20, ending on frame 50.

I did the following:

1. set a keyframe on frame 1 on the flow object (the one that creates the inflow) with the "Use Flow" checkbox off
2. on frame 20 i added another keyframe with the "Use Flow" checkbox on
3. on frame 50 i added another "Use Flow" checkbox on
4. on frame 51 i added another "Use Flow" checkbox off

the unwanted result is that i see the domain cube as an object (as the fluid material) that covers the whole animation from frame 1 to frame 20. [image: domain as an object from keyframe 1-20]

Comment: I don't know your scene but have you tried to keyframe the visibility of the fluid domain? Hide it from frame 1 to 19, run simulation from 20 to 50, then hide it again because it will be shown as a cube again when the simulation has ended. Alternatively, you can do a cut in the animation after the simulation has ended. The fluid can be converted to a mesh to make it static (but this depends on how you render it).

Comment: Yes. Doesn’t work. It doesn’t start the flow animation.

Comment: Do you bake the liquid simulation from frame 1 to 50? In my scene, it works. The liquid is baked from frame 1 to 190 but hidden in render and viewport ("camera" and "monitor" icons) until frame 110. The *Use Flow* checkbox is disabled. At frame 110 the domain becomes visible and *Use Flow* is enabled. The liquid flows.

Answer (score 0):

For Blender 3.1

1. Go to domain.
2. Select *Particle Properties*
3. Select *Liquid*

Set keyframes on *Show Emitter* for render and for *Viewport Display*.